# Why does this javascript not move the box when keys are pressed, as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a box that moves when the 'A' or 'D' keys are pressed. This is the code that I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function left(id)
    {
        var y = '-5';
        var z =document.getElementById(id).style.left;
        u = parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.left;

        document.getElementById(id).style.left = u;

    } 

        function right(id)
        {
            var r = '5';
            var z =document.getElementById(id).style.left;
            u = parseInt(r)+parseInt(z);
            var state = document.getElementById(id).style.left;

            document.getElementById(id).style.left = u;

        }



    event.onkeyUp = KeyCheck();
    function KeyCheck()
    {
        var KeyID = event.keyCode;

        switch(KeyID)
        {
            case 97: left("y");
            break; 
            case 100: right("y");
            break;


        }

    } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:absolute; height:50px; width:50px; left:100px; right:100px; top:500px; background-color:#03C;" id="y">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should indicate your question more clearly.  What do you want answered?  If you want to share code, use github. If you want a question answered, ask one here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)  As @Mario says, your question should really be related to a particular issue you're having with your code.  If it's not working, try to state what it's doing/not doing and what you'd like it to do.  Posting code is great, but without a description it's more difficult for people to diagnose and many people don't have time to work it out without an accurate description of the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

[I fixed your JavaScript for you](http://jsbin.com/utavu4/edit):

```
//was:        event.onkeyUp = KeyCheck();     calls KeyCheck(); assigns result!
           document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;    // assigns function object KeyCheck


//was: function KeyCheck()             ignores Event object argument!
       function KeyCheck(e)            // need to inspect Event object that is passed
       {

//was:     var KeyID = event.keyCode;  event is not related to this callback!
           var KeyID = e.keyCode;      // get keyCode property from passed object

           switch(KeyID)
           {
               case 65: left("y");     // need to use ASCII codes for uppercase
               break; 
               case 68: right("y");
               break;
           }
       }
```

However, as [Town suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984851/i-need-to-do-a-simple-moving-box-this-is-the-code-that-i-have-with-the-use-of-a/5985099#5985099), there are better ways to accomplish this (with jQuery).

Comment: +1 Leftium, you're a saint :)  `100` is 4 on the numeric keypad though - it's right in your demo just not in the answer ;)

Comment: @Town: and you beat me to the jQuery solution while I was debugging the pure JS version

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is tagged as plain JavaScript and many people hate library-based answers to plain Javascript questions, but i'd really recommend using a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do this so that you don't have to worry about browser quirks regarding keycode handling and event hookups.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var moveBy;

    switch (e.which) {
    case 65: // a
        moveBy = -10;
        break;
    case 68: // d
        moveBy = 10;
        break;
    }
    $('div').css('left', function() {
        var l = parseInt($(this).css("left"));
        $(this).css("left", (l + moveBy) + "px");
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo on jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/7AsBq/)

It's also worth noting that jQuery 1.6 introduced relative values to [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) which would mean that you could simplify that code even further, but there's currently a bug that prevents it from working - planned to be fixed in 1.6.2.